# Using import.meta is causing test to fails (Jest + React + Typescript + Vite)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite, ts-jest

On an app that was initially setup with Create-react-app and then migrated to jest, the tests started to fail because of the import.meta
By some reason the import.meta situation, I was solved on the .tsx files with the usage of the library ts-jest-mock-import-meta, but on .ts they keep failing.

I have setup my jest.config.ts the following way:

```
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        diagnostics: {
          ignoreCodes: [1343],
        },
        astTransformers: {
          before: [
            {
              path: 'node_modules/ts-jest-mock-import-meta', // or, alternatively, 'ts-jest-mock-import-meta' directly, without node_modules.
              options: {
                metaObjectReplacement: {
                  API_ENDPOINT: 'https://www.url.com',
                  test2: 'test2',
                  test3: 'test3',
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png)$': '<rootDir>/src/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/test/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
  },
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  type: 'module',
};
```

I am making use of ts-jest-mock-import-meta library. Even though the problem was solved on the tsx files, i have some import.meta on ts files that are causing the tests to fail, by saying that the import.meta.env.API_ENDPOINT is undefined.

```
{
  "name": "test-env-event",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fetch-event-source": "^1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.14.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-jest-mock-import-meta": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

My package.json contains the following libs. Any help would be appreciated.

Another note is that i need to call my env variables conditionally, so they might in some cases be undefined:

```
const apiURL = import.meta.env.API_URL ? `${import.meta.env.API_URL}` : "http://localhost:8080"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved with the usage of the vite-plugin-environment and repacling the import.meta with process.env